# Xcode - View DWG(vector) files on ipad

Tags: xcode, ipad, view, cad, dwg

Is viewing DWG files currently possible on iPad?

I'm looking to make a simple application that will allow viewing CAD drawings.
Is it possible under the tools provided in Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

No. Not sure if the [Open Design Alliance](http://www.opendesign.com/) has iPhone ports of their library, but you can check.

If not, you can send them to a web server where you convert them.

Comment: What do you mean by send them to a web server where you can convert them?

Comment: You could write a web service on an operating system that OpenDesign supported.  Then your iPhone app would need to POST the file to your webservice to get back some format it could display.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is that you wish to have a View you can incorporate directly into your iOS program that renders DWG files directly as part of your UI, then I think the answer is still "no, this functionality is not available."

The Open Design Alliance has iOS ports of their library but no viewer.  You could use the ODA library to generate PDFs of the DWG drawings and view those directly in your application using an existing PDFView.

Or you can, as suggested, do this conversion on a server somewhere and just handle viewing the PDF (or JPEG or whatever you decide to convert to) locally.